# How do I specify a cursor position in an AutoHotKey snippet?

Tags: autohotkey

How do I specify a (update: keyboard) cursor position in an AutoHotKey snippet? For example:

```
::hkr::    
Send,    
(    
Hello,    

__cursorhere()    

Kind regards,    
Constantine    
)    
return
```

Answer (score 1):

```
::hkr::
SendInput,
(
Hello,



Kind regards,
Constantine
)
Send {Up 3} ; move the keyboard cursor at the middle of the text.
return
```

Another example:

```
::hkr::
SendInput,
(
Hello,

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. CARET_HERE It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum

Kind regards,
Constantine
)
Send {Up 2}{Ctrl Down}{Left 34}{Ctrl Up} ; move the keyboard cursor before the word "CARET_HERE".
return
```

Comment: It gives me:

"Hello,
caret coordinates: X32 Y1036

Kind regards,
Constantine"

I just wanted my keyboard cursor (caret) be at the middle of the text... Is not it possible?

Comment: It works. No more direct way? Sometimes I want the caret be in the middle of the (big) text.

Comment: What's  "the middle of the (big) text"? The middle of the page? The middle of the document?  The middle of the window?

Comment: Like in my example, but bigger. Something like this:

Comment: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. CARET_HERE It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."

Comment: And why has the cursor to be moved in the middle of this big text and not in the end (if you add this text instead of  __cursorhere() to your code) as in the above example? Without knowing the logic of what you're trying to do it's hard to say the best way of doing that.

Comment: Well, it depends. Different reasons from case to case. I gave you just an example of mechanics. If you want an example of semantics, here it is: "Hi, I can do the job for  __cursorhere() dollars." The logic behind that is I do not need to type "dollars" or use another snippet every time I bid. Competitors like Mahou and KeySwitcher can do this (AHK supposed to be a broader band solution, I suppose). I do not ask much...

Comment: In this case you have to calculate first how many words are between the current cursor's position and the position in that you wish to insert another text. See the edited answer.

Comment: So no more direct way. Thank you for your detailed example, easy to modify and use for everybody.